# Angular ng-class and objects from controller

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to use ng-class with styles created in a controller.
Something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-class="{0:minWidth1024, 1:minWidth1920}[1]">
```

and controller:

```
$scope.minWidth1920 = {
    'min-width': '1500px'
};
$scope.minWidth1024 = {
    'min-width': '440px'
};
```

The min-width style is not taking effect. But if I use it like this:

```
<style>
.minWidth1024{
    min-width: 440px;
}
.minWidth1920 {
    min-width: 1420px;
}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-class="{0:'minWidth1024', 1:'minWidth1920'}[1]">
```

Then it works fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just use `ng-style` and map the code from controller.

Comment: Yes, ng-style works. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers Mate ! Good Luck.